# Add spacing between numbers and letters

Tags: javascript, html, css

how to add spacing if i write "12345test" output is "1 2 3 4 5 t e s t"

This is my code

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Write something" 
                  id="testInput" value=""
   onFocus="getElementById('test').innerHTML=getElementById('testInput').value;datum();"   
   onKeyUp="getElementById('test').innerHTML=getElementById('testInput').value;">

<div style="z-index: 2; position: absolute; left: 10px; top: 100px; height: 29px; width: 400px; color: black; font-weight: bold; font-size: 26;">
   <span id="test"></span>
</div>
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `...innerHTML=getElementById(…).value.split('').join(' ')`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `letter-spacing` property in CSS:

```
...
letter-spacing: 5px;  /* will separate each character by 5 pixels */
...
```